# Create a constructor that does not exist in base class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class that expects an `IWorkspace` to be created:

```
public class MyClass {
    protected IWorkspace workspace;
    public MyClass(IWorkspace w) {
        this.workspace = w;
    }
}
```

and a derived class `Derived`. In this derived class I have a copy-constrcutor that should create an instance of `Derived` based on an instance of `MyClass`.

```
public class Derived : MyClass{
    public Derived(MyClass m) : base(m.workspace) { }
}
```

The above won´t compile with following error:

> Cannot access protected member MyClass.workspace' via a qualifier of type 'MyClass'; the qualifier must be of type 'Derived' (or derived from it)

So what I´m trying to achieve is copying the base-class´ members to the derived one and create into a new instance of the latter. The reason why I do not use a constructor for `IWorkspace` within my derived class is that I do not have any access to such a workspace within the client-code, only to the instance of `MyClass` to be copied.

Comment: Does `MyClass` have a default constructor?

Comment: Depending on your namespace you need an access modifier infront of MyClass - public,internal, etc....

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Nope, unfortunately

Comment: You can encapsulate `MyClass` instead of inheriting it.

Comment: @Helix88 classes without access modifiers default to `internal` unless they are nested.

Comment: @HimBromBeere And you need to use `IWorkspace` directly?

Comment: @HimBromBeere the comment wasn't directed at you, I was trying to tell Helix that the access modifier doesn't have anything to do with this error because it defaults to an acceptable value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't have access to `MyClass` source and `IWorkspace` isn't available, the best thing you can do is encapsulate `MyClass` instead of derive it, and have someone externally provide the dependencies:

```
public class MyClassWrapper
{
    private readonly MyClass myClass;
    public MyClassWrapper(MyClass myClass)
    {
        this.myClass = myClass;
    }

    // Wrap any methods you depend on here
}
```

If push comes to shove and you have no alternative, you can perhaps use reflection to get the `Workspace` instance from `MyClass`, but that would be an ugly hack.

Comment: You´re right, I do not even need this workspace directly, only for creation. I guess this might work, trying it out.